# Defining a function to play a graph from CSV data - Python panda

Tags: pandas, data-analysis

I am trying to play around with data analysis, taking in data from a simple CSV file I have created with random values in it.

I have defined a function that should allow the user to type in a value3 then from the dataFrame, plot a bar graph. The below:

```
def analysis_currency_pair():
    x=raw_input("what currency pair would you like to analysie ? :")
    print type(x)
    global dataFrame
    df1=dataFrame
    df2=df1[['currencyPair','amount']]
    df2 = df2.groupby(['currencyPair']).sum()
    df2 = df2.loc[x].plot(kind = 'bar')
```

When I call the function, the code returns my question, along with giving the output of the currency pair. However, it doesn't seem to put x (the value input by the user) into the later half of the function, and so no graph is produced.

Am I doing something wrong here?

This code works when we just put the value in, and not within a function.

I am confused!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Sorry! I pressed enter instead of typing out more!
The code doesn't work , it returns:
  
         ` ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'EURUSD'`

Comment: I think you can add sample of your input data.

Comment: Hi,
Cant put the data on here unfortunately!
so the data works, for example:

Comment: Hi,
Cant put the data on here unfortunately!
so the data works, for example:
    dataFrame = get_trade(datetime(2016,01,06,10,00,00), datetime.now())
df=dataFrame

Comment: Hmmm, I dont know what is `get_trade`, but function `analysis_currency_pair` wants string from column `currencyPair`, because function `groupby` return index from column `currencyPair`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need rewrite your function with two parameters: `x` and `df`, which are passed to function `analysis_currency_pair`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"currencyPair": pd.Series({1: 'EURUSD', 2: 'EURGBP', 3: 'CADUSD'}), 
                   "amount": pd.Series({1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 3.5}),
                   "a": pd.Series({1: 7, 2: 8, 3: 9})})

print df

#   a  amount currencyPair
#1  7     2.0       EURUSD
#2  8     2.0       EURGBP
#3  9     3.5       CADUSD

def analysis_currency_pair(x, df1):
    print type(x)
    df2=df1[['currencyPair','amount']]
    df2 = df2.groupby(['currencyPair']).sum()
    df2 = df2.loc[x].plot(kind = 'bar')

#raw input is EURUSD or EURGBP or CADUSD
pair=raw_input("what currency pair would you like to analysie ? :")

analysis_currency_pair(pair, df)
```

Or you can pass string to function `analysis_currency_pair`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"currencyPair": [ 'EURUSD', 'EURGBP', 'CADUSD', 'EURUSD', 'EURGBP'], 
                    "amount": [ 1,  2,  3, 4, 5],
                    "amount1": [ 5,  4,  3, 2, 1]})

print df

#   amount  amount1 currencyPair
#0       1        5       EURUSD
#1       2        4       EURGBP
#2       3        3       CADUSD
#3       4        2       EURUSD
#4       5        1       EURGBP

def analysis_currency_pair(x, df1):
    print type(x)

    #<type 'str'>
    df2=df1[['currencyPair','amount']]
    df2 = df2.groupby(['currencyPair']).sum()
    print df2

    #              amount
    #currencyPair        
    #CADUSD             3
    #EURGBP             7
    #EURUSD             5   

    df2 = df2.loc[x].plot(kind = 'bar')

analysis_currency_pair('CADUSD', df)
```

Comment: Perfect! that is what I am after!

So it was because of not passing through the function with my 2 parameters!

Thanks so much :)

Comment: Jezrael , Apologies! What do you mean by accepting your answer?